# GetKeyState doesn't work in Windows 2000 (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, directx, mouse

I have just tested my DirectX game on a Windows 2000 SP4 system but it won't receive **any** mouse clicks!

This is how I check for mouse clicks :

```
    unsigned int mButtons = 0;
    if (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0) mButtons |= HIDBoss::MOUSE_LEFT;
    if (GetKeyState(VK_RBUTTON) < 0) mButtons |= HIDBoss::MOUSE_RIGHT;
    if (GetKeyState(VK_MBUTTON) < 0) mButtons |= HIDBoss::MOUSE_MIDDLE;
    if (GetKeyState(VK_XBUTTON1) < 0) mButtons |= HIDBoss::MOUSE_4;
    if (GetKeyState(VK_XBUTTON2) < 0) mButtons |= HIDBoss::MOUSE_5;
```

etc...

This code works perfectly on Windows 7 and XP 32/64bit.

The problem is **fixed** if I use the **OIS** library instead - which uses DirectX input - but it contains a few bugs so I would rather avoid it.

Can anyone suggest why GetKeyState won't work on W2K? Could it be because the system hasn't been updated - through Windows Update - for the last couple of years..?

Thank you for your time,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work but I'd recommend using [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293(v=VS.85).aspxgenerated.) instead.

**Edit**: In answer to your comment.  It is merely a suggestion but its, equally, pretty easy to find out if the buttons are swapped by calling:

```
GetSystemMetrics(SM_SWAPBUTTON)
```

Your big problem arises from the fact that GetKeyState is not supposed to return a value for mouse buttons only keyboard buttons.  the fact it DOES work in some OSs is not something you are supposed to be able to rely on across all OSs.

> An application calls GetKeyState in
> response to a keyboard-input message.
> This function retrieves the state of
> the key when the input message was
> generated.

Its worth noting that it makes specific mention of calling it in response to a keyboard-input message (ie WM_KEY[UP/DOWN]).  Equally there is no mention that this should work for mice.  As such you really are better off just using GetAsyncKeyState...

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on this? The docs say that it returns the physical button events rather than the logical "mapped" ones. Is there a good reason why I should "confuse" those users who are used to clicking the other way round? Of course I will try it and if it does work, then that's a good enough reason! But is there something else I should be aware of? Thanks!